# VBA: How to convert word ASCII A1 to web quote when read from doc

Tags: vba, ms-word

e.g.

In doc is:

```
I am from "Moon"
```

Read via VBA, " will be ASCII A1, I use Replace change Chr(161) to web-displayed quote, but seems useless.

VBA Code:

```
Value = .Rows(i).Cells(2).Range.Text
Value = Replace(Value, Chr(161), "&quot;")
```

Anyone know how?

Comment: which version of word is it, and which version of VBA scripting language are you using when you get the error?

Comment: Will not get error. I use word 2010, vba 7.0

Comment: Always a good idea to show your code.

Comment: Describe :"useless"? Does the replace work? Or does it not display correctly on the web?

Comment: Did you try using CHRB Keyword instead of CHR Keyword.

Answer (score 0):

`Chr(161)` is ¡, not a quote mark.  If you want to match a Windows-1262 curly quote, you want `Chr(147)` and `Chr(148)`.